# How to use SSL with visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) on how to create MVC 5 application with external login. The problem is that when I get to the step that uses SSL (https) I dont get the proper warnings (that are supposed to make my content trusted on IE and Chrome after SSL) that the guy in the tutorial gets, so whatever browser I run it on I get a warning of untrusted content.

Even in the tutorial the guy gets it for Firefox since "Firefox uses its own certificate store, so it will display a warning". How do you bypass this? I dont want every firefox user to get a warning when they access my website.

So basically, How do I get browsers to trust my site after I enabled SSL?

To make it more clear here is some code I use to enable https-requirement:

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
            filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        }
    }
```

And then to allow my Homepage and LoginPage to be accessed without authorization:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demo you are following talks about using a self signed certificate, this should be used for local testing purposes only, it produces a valid certificate with no trusted certificate authority (CA), this means that no user will automatically trust it.  You can read more about self signed certificates [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate).

In the demo you are instructed to trust the certificate, this installs it on **your** local certificate store so you are no longer prompted, it is up to you to determine whether you trust this certificate or not as it does not come from a trusted CA.  This does not approve it for use for any other user, any user browsing to your **test** site will also get the same prompt.

When you are ready for other users to use your site, you should provide a valid certificate from a trusted CA, unless this is an internal site and your company already has [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) then you will need to purchase one, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404907/where-could-i-buy-a-valid-ssl-certificate) or [here](https://www.startssl.com/?app=1) for a free one.

If you host your site on Azure and don't mind using the azurewebsites.net domain, then you get ssl for free.  If you want to use your own host name and use Azure, then you will need to change to a Standard site, @troy-hunt has a good write up on how to achieve this [here](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/09/the-complete-guide-to-loading-free-ssl.html).